# Cant run my app in android studio how can i fix it?

Tags: windows-10

[enter image description here][1]

Error running 'app': No target device found.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWmmt.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **target device** where your app should run on.

Just edit your run configuration by going to run -> edit configuration -> (yourapp) -> deployment target ; then  choose a target device  then run your app again.